# Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) : attempt to use zero-length variable name

Tags: r, dataframe

I was working in my laptop but and my code run without error. I used the same code and data in my PC but I get this error. I do not know what is the problem! everything was working in my laptop.

I have a .RDA file and when I view(my file) it seems good. I can delete some column and work with data.  but when I want to use the

```
  library(dplyr)
       df<-df %>% mutate(`6-17` = 1* (AGE > 6 & AGE <= 17), `18-30`= 1*(AGE > 18 & AGE <= 30), `31-40` = 1* (AGE > 31 & AGE <= 40), `+41` = 1* (AGE > 41),  )
```

I get that error!

Comment: You can use `cut` to create the groups

Comment: but how if I wanna use the same code?

Comment: Try it on a fresh session if the code is working fine earlier

Comment: it works in my laptop,

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have same version of R and package version on your laptop and PC.

```
getRversion()
packageVersion("dplyr")
```

Comment: no they are not the same. should I update package version?

Comment: Yes! you should update the packages using `update.packages()`. if you want a specific version, then remove the package and then install specific version that worked for you using `install.packages("dplyr", version ="XXX")`